# Scale factor of pgfplot's xtick with mask

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

A scale factor `factor` for `xtick`s does not work with ldots mask `...`. Does the problem have a solution?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function ={
        factor=2;
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        %xtick = {-2*factor,2*factor}, % This one work
        %xtick = {-2,...,2}, % This one work
        xtick = {-2*factor,...,2*factor}, % This one doesn't work
        ]
        \addplot+[blue, no marks, domain={-6:6}] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `/pgf/foreach/parse=true`, see p. 989 of pgfmanual v3.1.4

[image]

This works (at least in in this case).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/foreach/parse=true,%<-added
    declare function ={
        factor=2;
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        %xtick = {-2*factor,2*factor}, % This one work
        %xtick = {-2,...,2}, % This one work
        xtick={-2*factor,...,2*factor}, % This one works now
        ]
        \addplot+[blue, no marks, domain={-6:6}] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me mention that I recommend not to overdo it with `parse=true`, there are cases with integers in which I had some difficulties.

Just in case you encounter problems with this proposal because some other, perhaps internal, loop causes problems: you could also use `xtickmin` and `xtickmax`, whose values get automatically parsed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function ={
        factor=2;
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        xtickmin=-2*factor,
        xtickmax=2*factor,
        ]
        \addplot+[blue, no marks, domain={-6:6}] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```